# SendKeys or SendTextEntry to a game

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want to make a program to save some server IP addresses and use one of them whenever the user want to use it.

And the game does not support to the copy paste command. So player have to waste time by typing IP addresses if he wants to join to another server.

I want to make my program to type the address in the IP address box in the game when user pressed the F12 button. F12 keydown is captured using a keyhook class without any problem.

The problem is game does not respond to either the SendKeys or CodePlex InputSimulator class. (I've tried to send each number using SendKey class, and tried to send TextEnry using InputSimulator). How can I do this ? The only thing game capture is keyboard keys. Is there anyway to make signals the keyboard sends to the computer when user pressed a button ?

By the way the game is Microsoft Halo CE (Custom Edition)

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to move the cursor or simulate clicks for other applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849421/how-to-move-the-cursor-or-simulate-clicks-for-other-applications)

see Pietu1998's answer about uiaccess

Right click on your project and do "Add-->New Item"

Choose Application Manifest File.

Change:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

to:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="true" />
```

Comment: whoa.. Isnt there any more simple way than the link u have given ? Im very beginner to C#. And what did u mean by SendInput ? C# doesnot have a class in that name ? U mean SendKeys ?

Comment: I updated my post with how to set uiAccess.  If that doesn't work then you can look at SendInput, but there is a good chance that setting uiAccess to true will fix your problem.

Comment: :D Thank u so much.. U saved the day :)
By the way "asInvolder" and "true" doesnot working :). It shows an error after I clicked the debug button.. I used "highestAvailable" and  "false" :D Its working..
By the way I didnt know about the Application Manifest file in winforms before u said this :) I though they are only exist in winrt apps.. Thanks :D