# Can't find button programmatically

Tags: c#

I wrote a program which programmatically presses the "Install" button on a WebPlatformInstaller., but it doesn't find this button. Can you help me fix this code?

Windows: 00030590
Text:    Install
Class:   WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.378734a
Style:   5601000B

This is my code:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("WebPlatformInstaller");

foreach (Process p in processes)// debug shows that there is 1 process
{
   IntPtr ButtonHandle = FindWindowEx(p.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "Install", null);
   SendMessage(ButtonHandle, BM_CLICK, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

}
```

Comment: I'm not even going to ask why you want to auto-click the "Install" button of a setup...

Comment: Because I didn't find example, how programmatically install Azure Powershell via c#.

Comment: why shouldn't use SendKeys.Send(); ?

Comment: @SamanGholami Maybe it is just a separate process.

Comment: You could try the AutomationElement class.

Comment: Because it's console program, And when I tried  send keys, the program throw exception.

Comment: For the SendKeys problem you could see my answer at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934577/sendkeys-or-sendtextentry-to-a-game

Comment: SendKeys kinda sucks most of the time anyways. I prefer winapi myself for stuff like this.

Comment: Also, you are passing 'Install' as the class name parameter. I'm guessing 'Install' is the text of the button. If it was me I would be making friends with Spy++ right now and look at understanding the hierarchy of the app you are trying send messages to. Then investigate the use of GetWindow because FindWindowEx is not going to do it alone.

Comment: @MikeCheel just noticed that myself... looks like the issue. Should it be "WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.378734a"?

Comment: @geedubb Actually your advice didn't works.