# Get program to send input to a game

Tags: c#, .net, sendkeys

I'm trying to make a c# application that every specified amount of time will press the specified button. My goal for this program is to run a game (MineCraft for example) and get the player to automatically jump to avoid afk kicks.

I've got it working but it will only send the characters if you are using notepad or some other textbox. It doesn't work in MineCraft or Terraria.

Heres the line of code that runs in order to simulate a keypress:

```
SendKeys.SendWait(buttonToPress);
```

I've done some searching and this page I found didn't help with my topic.

[SendKeys or SendTextEntry to a game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934577/sendkeys-or-sendtextentry-to-a-game)

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop

Comment: Honestly you would be better off with a premade tool designed for this kind of stuff like [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: I don't think that would work because I'm making this program for me and my friends to enjoy and that will only work on a computer with autohotkey installed.

Comment: Just as your C# program would need to be on the computer. You can do what you want in one line with AHK.

Comment: So with AHK I can make an executable that will run even without AHK installed on it?

Comment: @tjpc3TheRedstoner Yes, it comes with Ahk2exe.exe which will let you compile and run Autohotkey scripts without the program installed.