# Simulating mouse scrollwheel using other keys

Tags: c#, mouse, scrollwheel

I've been thinking about buying a old IBM mouse, but it does not have a scrollwheel on it. So I started searching for a program which would make me able to scroll up and down. I've found a couple of them, but it was not what I was looking for.

So, I was thinking about writing a program to do that for me, though I wanted to be able to scroll up and down by holding SHIFT and pressing either left or right button on my mouse. Do you have any idea if there's some kind of method which makes you able to scroll up and down in C#? Thanks a lot, I appreciate it.

Comment: Check out the "SendInput" method. http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendinput

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my post on: [How to move the cursor or simulate clicks for other applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849421/how-to-move-the-cursor-or-simulate-clicks-for-other-applications)

Call the ScrollWheel method.

I call:

```
MouseInput.ScrollWheel( -1 );
```

to scroll one line.

Also, make sure you look at the part about:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="true" />
```

In another answer.