# Redirect from one form in c# to another form in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

How to move from one form in C# to another form in VB.net?

I tried this code:

```
Process b = new Process();
this.Hide();
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"D:\Fingerprint System\Fingerprint System\bin\Debug\Fingerprint System.exe");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
SendKeys.SendWait("{Enter}");
```

But it opens the main form in VB.net which is `form1`, and I want to open another form in VB.net which is `form4`.

Comment: then why tage `C`?

Comment: sorry i mean c# ,haha

Comment: Just a Suggestion which doesnt answer you original question: You should use `process.WaitForInputIdle();` instead of `Thread.Sleep()`... Hans Passant did write a nice answer regarding this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41016530/6952884

Answer (score 0):

Change the startup form in your `vb.net` project to that of `form4` so that when you launch the `Fingerprint System.exe` the form you desire is the one launched by default.

If the behavior you wanted is more complex than that you could always leverage command line arguments when launching the executable that correspond to a form you would like to be shown.

Comment: but if i try this solution the main page(form1 will not open first) , my idea is to open form1 in vb.net and then move to c# form after that move to form4 in vb.net

Comment: If the behavior you wanted is more complex than that you could always leverage command line arguments when launching the executable that correspond to a form you would like to be shown. Can you explain it more?

Comment: @درةالتقى Basically just have a switch statement at your programs entry point that switches on an argument that corresponds to the form that you want to open.